# LibGDX background image not fitting the whole screen

Tags: java, libgdx, android, image

I'm trying to add a background image to the game's main menu, and when I execute the game as a Desktop Application it fits OK,

[image: running as desktop app]

but if I execute it on a movile device (or using a virtual device) it doesn't completely fit.

[image: running as android app]

I tried changing the image's size, position, etc... but those two blue empty spaces keep being there above and below.

The code:

```
Texture backgroundImg=game.getManager().get("...");

...

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    ...
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(backgroundImg,0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 1.75f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 1.75f);
    game.batch.end();

    ...

}
```

Comment: You should create your menu with a table https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table

Comment: @Curio thanks for the tip,  but that has nothing to do with my problem right?

Comment: Why that *1.75f?

Comment: @Curio i wanted to zoom the image a bit. Same happens without 1.75f